# Java program not reading environment variable set from command line

Tags: java, maven

In my java program I am trying to use few native libraries. Everything works fine if I use my **intelij IDE** to run code, however if I ran the code from command line (from terminal) it gives me library linkage error

I am using **Mac OS Sierra** and **Java 1.8**

Following is my pom.xml looks like.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/</argLine>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/</DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Java code**

```
   @Test
    public void testCPLX(){
        System.out.println("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env: " +System.getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"));
        IloOplFactory oplF = new IloOplFactory();
    }
```

if I run this code form InteliJ IDE it runs and prints the value of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as `/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/`

However if run the program using following command.

> mvn clean test -Dtest=test.java.cplexTests.TestCplex

I get `null` for `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and so the library linkage error in next step.

I tried setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH path before running `mvn` command however it's not helping. I tried setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as part of `mvn` command, it's not helping either.

**First Try**

> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/
>
> mvn clean test -Dtest=test.java.cplexTests.TestCplex

**Second Try**

> mvn -DDYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/ -Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/ -Dtest=test.java.cplexTests.TestCplex clean test

If I remove `environmentVariables` section from `maven` I get same error when I run through InteliJ Idea.

Comment: The command line argument must be `-Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/`. Java will look into *java.library.path* (by default) and not your *DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH*.

Comment: @PeterMmm if that's the case if then why do I get the same error when I remove `environmentVariables` section from `maven`

Comment: Propably the library needs this environment var too (?) Do you `System.load()` the lib anywhere in your code ? Ahh ... DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is a special name on OSX. I didn't know this...

Comment: I found out that Mac doesn't allow to set `LYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. so created a soft link under `/usr/local/lib` however still getting the same error. any clue ?

Comment: Are you sure you have `environmentVariables` correct? Is this http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, I am pretty sure about that, as removing that gives me same error i get when I run from terminal.for your reference http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#environmentVariables